# Can mosquitto forward the ClientID of a messages sender?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I am using the [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) MQTT Broker.
Also, I have multiple (currently 10, but the number will increase) clients that publish some sensor data periodically to topic `A`. These clients are technically identical, but do have a unique identifier (serial number).

I also have a client that subscribes topic `A` in order to receive the published messages and persist the sensor valus in a database.
I certainly need to know **which** Sensor (i.e. client) has sent a particular value.

As a solution, one could just append some Sensor ID to the payload of each published message. But since the sensors access the broker via GSM, I need to keep the traffic low, so I am trying to avoid that.

I assume, the Broker itself knows **which message** comes from **which client**, especially when using perisistent connections, i.e. `clean_session=False`. Is that correct?
If yes, is there any chance that the subscribing clients can obtain the `client_id` when receiving the message?
Can it be configured in mosquitto? Or is it default behavior and I am missing something?

I am using [paho-mqtt 1.3.1](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/) for all clients.

Answer (score 3):

No, the client id is not part of a published message. It is only used to identify the client to the broker when the connection is established in order to determine if stored messages and persistent subscriptions should be honoured.

The easiest solution is to use a separate topic for each sensor but with a shared root. e.g.

- sensor 1 publishes to `A/1`
- sensor 2 published to `A/2`

The client would then subscribe to `A/+` this would then receive all the messages and can use the second half of the topic to determine which sensor it came from.

The other options is as you suggested which is to include the id in the payload.

Comment: I thought of this, too. But including the serial in the topic will still increase the traffic. Is there a chance that the broker appends the clientId to the message?

Comment: No, the broker has no way to modify the message

Answer (score 0):

Sending the client-id with payload(message) is possible. But you need to use delimiters in payload(message) at publisher side . *Example: Publisher sends the payload as "client-ID=3 - temperature = 29 " .* At the subscriber side , you remove the delimiters using *strtok()* . 
There is no configuration available at broker side.

Answer (score 0):

1. Per my experience with mosquitto, I don't think there is an option for mosquitto to change either the topic or the payload when re-publishing a received message.
2. However, I think it is just an implementation issue. 
   Theoretically, I think it is OK and good to support such kind of feature, since it does not violate MQTT specification at all.
   (http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/csprd02/mqtt-v3.1.1-csprd02.html#_Toc385349773, Section 3.3.2.1)

   ```
   However, since the Server is permitted to override the Topic Name,  
   it might not be the same as the Topic Name in the original PUBLISH Packet.
   ```
3. The pratical solution for your current problem is, as pointed by @hardillb, either publishing using different topics but receiving using a topic with wildcard (+ or #), or, containing publisher information in payload.